# Windows Explorer doesn't detect optical drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, dvd, compact-disc

Recently I've had a weird problem with Windows 10. Sometimes the OS wouldn't show the optical drive in Windows Explorer and it can't be accessed by other software. Rebooting makes the OS detect the disc but when it is ejected and another disc is inserted the problem recurs.
[image: Just after booting Windows detects the optical drive and gives it a letter]
[image: After ejecting the disc the drive loses its letter]
[image: When another disc is inserted it is detected correctly but not shown in Windows Explorer]
[image: When I try to set the drive letter...]
[image: ...a cryptic error message appears]

Comment: Does this happen with several different disks, or just one? If it's just one disk the problem is likely the disk, but multiple, it could be the drive or the OS. Have you run the various Windows 10 repair functions: chkdisk, and dism repair?

Comment: It happens with all optical discs.